# CSS selector equivalent of this one

Tags: xpath, scrapy, css-selectors

I don't know how to put this class name in css selector because of the space. Could you help me please. Thank you!

'//div[@class="posting-card super-highlighted "]' <===

'div.posting-card super-highlighted' - doesn't work
'div."posting-card super-highlighted"' - neither

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always remember to replace space with `.` between the classes in css.

```
div.posting-card.super-highlighted
```